# How to use an array value or variable as a key with scriptDB?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is this possible? If I have an array like this

```
[[1,1,5000],[2,1,3000],[5,6,1000]]
```

is it possible to put it into scriptDB in a format like this?

```
{
 customerName: 'Steve',
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .

 1: 
 {
   itemID: 1,
   qty: 1,
   cost: 5000
 },
 2: 
 {
   itemID: 2,
   qty: 1,
   cost: 3000
 },
 5: 
 {
   itemID: 5,
   qty: 6,
   cost: 1000
 }
}
```

If this doesn't happen to be possible what is the best option to store these so that I could query by itemID?

Comment: Did you try it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible but NOT desired for many reasons: 1) there is a limit on how big a value csn be in a key,value pair so eventually it will bust when a costumer has many items. 2) you cant query those items without getting the entire customer and manually looping all items.
Much better normalize it so each 'row' (key,value) is an item which a customer property.